# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined and other errors

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, steam

Whenever I try to run the JS code with node in CMD I get this error:

Oh and the bot probably cannot be run since stackoverflow needs permission from mySQL database.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Query._callback (C:\Users\George\Desktop\bot2\websitebot.js:138:9)
at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\George\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:86:24)
at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\George\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:94:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\George\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:280:23)
at Parser.write (C:\Users\George\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:74:12)
at Protocol.write (C:\Users\George\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\George\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:109:28)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
```

This is the code I'm trying to run, I honestly have no idea why I am getting these errors. Incase someone here might help me:

```js
//The required liberys for the bot to work
var Steam = require('steam')
var SteamUser = require('steam-user');
var SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');
var SteamConfirm = require('steamcommunity-mobile-confirmations');
var SteamTradeOffers = require('steam-tradeoffers');
var TradeOfferManager = require('steam-tradeoffer-manager');
var TOTP = require('onceler').TOTP;
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');
 
var offers = new SteamTradeOffers();
 
var apik = 'xxx'; //The API Key of the bot.
var botsteamid = 'xxx'; //The SteamID of the bot.
var identitysecret = 'xxx'; //The identity secret of the bot.
var sharedsecret = 'xxx'; //The shared secret of the bot
 
 
var botusername = 'xxx';
var botpassword = 'xxx';
 
var admin = 'xxx'; //The steamid of the Admin.
var botid = 'xxx'; //The ID of the bot..
 
var pooling_interval  = 10000; // 10 seconds by default, the bot checks for outgoing confirmations every X seconds, defined here
 
//Setting up device identity
var deviceid=SteamTotp.getDeviceID(botsteamid);
 
 
//Making the bot log in.
var details = {
    "accountName"   : botusername, // Bot username
    "password"      : botpassword, // Bot password
    "twoFactorCode" : SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(sharedsecret)
};
 
var client = new SteamUser();
 
var manager = new TradeOfferManager({
    "steam"    : client,
    "domain"   : "localhost", //localhost
    "language" : "en",
})
 
//Setting up the MySQL Connection - This is where I have errors.
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'xxx', // MYSQL , LEAVE IT AS LOCALHOST IF YOU RUN IT ON THE SAME SERVER AS THE WEBSITE AND DATABASE
  user     : 'xxx', // MYSQL USERNAME
  password : 'xxx', // MYSQL PASSWORD
  database : 'xxx', // MYSQL DATABASENAME
  charset  : 'utf8_general_ci'
});
 
connection.connect();
 
client.logOn(details);
 
 
//Checking mobile confirmations
function checkConfirmations(steamcommunityMobileConfirmations){
    steamcommunityMobileConfirmations.FetchConfirmations((function (err, confirmations)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                console.log('Confirmations error: '+err);
                if(err=='Error: 503') // This is an error you can most likely ignore, except if it's spammed a lot - To fix it simply restart the bot
                {
                   
                }
                if(err=='Error: Invalid protocol: steammobile:') // - To fix it simply restart the bot
                {
                    // A fix should be coming soon!
                }
                return;
            }
            if(confirmations.length>0)
            {
                console.log('[SERVER] Received ' + confirmations.length + ' confirmations');
            }
            if ( ! confirmations.length)
            {
                return;
            }
            steamcommunityMobileConfirmations.AcceptConfirmation(confirmations[0], (function (err, result)
            {
                if (err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('[SERVER] Confirmation handling result: ' + result);
            }).bind(this));
        }).bind(this));
}
 
//Done with the functions, time to do commands.
 
//Logging the bot in
client.on('loggedOn', function(details)
{
    client.on('webSession', function(sessionID, cookies){
        manager.setCookies(cookies, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('setCookies error: '+err);
            process.exit(1); // Fatal error since we couldn't get our API key
            return;
        }
        var steamapi=manager.apiKey;
        var SteamcommunityMobileConfirmations = require('steamcommunity-mobile-confirmations');
        var steamcommunityMobileConfirmations = new SteamcommunityMobileConfirmations(
        {
            steamid:         botsteamid,
            identity_secret: identitysecret,
            device_id:       deviceid,
            webCookie:       cookies,
        });
        setInterval(function(){
            checkConfirmations(steamcommunityMobileConfirmations)
        }, pooling_interval);
        console.log("[SERVER] The Bot has logged in!");
        client.addFriend(admin);
        client.setPersona(Steam.EPersonaState.LookingToTrade);
        });
       
        offers.setup({
    sessionID: sessionID,
    webCookie: cookies,
    APIKey: apik
});
 
    });
});
 
function checkWithdraw(){
connection.query("SELECT * FROM `withdraw` WHERE active=1  AND `botid`='"+botid+"' AND tradestatus='Queued' LIMIT 1", function(err, row, fields) {
if (!row.length) {                                                  
    return;
}  
var tradeid = row[0].id;
 
var sendItems = (row[0].assetids).split(',');
var item=[],num = 0;
for (i = 0; i < sendItems.length; i++) {
    item[num] = {
        appid: 730,
        contextid: 2,
        amount: 1,
        assetid: sendItems[i]
    }
num++;
}
    offers.makeOffer ({
        partnerSteamId: row[0].steamid,
        accessToken: row[0].token,
        itemsFromMe: item,
        itemsFromThem: [],
        message: 'Withdraw from '
       
      },
      function(err, response) {
        if (err) { 
        console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log('Tradeoffer sent to ' + row[0].steamid);
        tradeofferquery = response;
        tradeofferid = (tradeofferquery['tradeofferid']);
        connection.query('UPDATE `withdraw` SET `tradeid`=\''+tradeofferid+'\', `tradestatus`="Sent" WHERE `id`=\''+tradeid+'\'', function(err, row, fields) {});
      })
     
});
}
 
function checkDeposit(){
connection.query("SELECT * FROM `deposits` WHERE `credited`=\'0\' AND `tradestatus`=\'Queued\' AND `botid`='"+botid+"' LIMIT 1", function(err, row, fields) {
if (!row.length) {                                                  
    return
}  
 
offers.getHoldDuration({partnerSteamId: row[0].steamid, accessToken: row[0].token}, function(err, response)
{
    if (err)
    {
        return;
    }
    escrowduration = response;
    thesd = (escrowduration['their']);
    if(thesd === 0){
       
   
var tradeid = row[0].id;
 
var sendItems = (row[0].assetids).split(',');
var item=[],num = 0;
for (i = 0; i < sendItems.length; i++) {
    item[num] = {
        appid: 730,
        contextid: 2,
        amount: 1,
        assetid: sendItems[i]
    }
num++;
}
console.log(item);
    offers.makeOffer ({
        partnerSteamId: row[0].steamid,
        accessToken: row[0].token,
        itemsFromMe: [],
        itemsFromThem: item,
        message: 'Deposit to , code: ' + row[0].code
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log('Tradeoffer sent to ' + row[0].steamid);
        tradeofferquery = response;
        tradeofferid = (tradeofferquery['tradeofferid']);
        connection.query('UPDATE `deposits` SET `tradeid`=\''+tradeofferid+'\', `tradestatus`="Sent" WHERE `id`=\''+tradeid+'\'', function(err, row, fields) {});
      })
 
    } else {
        connection.query('DELETE FROM `deposits` WHERE `steamid`=\''+ row[0].steamid +'\'', function(err, row, fields) {});
        console.log('They are in escrow');
    }    
});
 
});
 
}
 
//Keeping track of sent offers.
manager.on('sentOfferChanged', function(offer, oldState) {
    console.log("Offer #" + offer.id + " changed: " + TradeOfferManager.getStateName(oldState) + " -> " + TradeOfferManager.getStateName(offer.state));
    connection.query('UPDATE `deposits` SET `tradestatus`=\''+TradeOfferManager.getStateName(offer.state)+'\' WHERE `tradeid`=\''+offer.id+'\'');
    connection.query('UPDATE `withdraw` SET `tradestatus`=\''+TradeOfferManager.getStateName(offer.state)+'\' WHERE `tradeid`=\''+offer.id+'\'');
    if(offer.state == TradeOfferManager.ETradeOfferState.Accepted) {
    offer.getReceivedItems(function(err, items) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Couldn't get received items: " + err);
            } else {
               
            items.forEach(function(item)
        {
            console.log('Recieved: ' + item.name);
            connection.query('INSERT INTO `bank` (`botid`,`assetid`,`img`,`name`,`status`) VALUES (\''+botid+'\',\''+item.assetid+'\',\''+item.icon_url+'\',\''+item.market_name+'\',\'1\')', function(err, row, fields) {});
       
        })
       
            }
        });
    }
    if(offer.state != (TradeOfferManager.ETradeOfferState.Accepted || TradeOfferManager.ETradeOfferState.Active)) {
    connection.query('DELETE FROM `deposits` WHERE `tradeid`=\''+offer.id+'\'');
    connection.query('DELETE FROM `withdraw` WHERE `tradeid`=\''+offer.id+'\'');
    }
});
 
 
 
 
//Processing incomming offers
manager.on('newOffer', function(offer)
{
    offer.decline(function(err)
            {
                console.log('[DEBUG] Declined Counter offer.');
                if (err)
                {
                    console.log('Decline error: '+err);
                }
                connection.query('DELETE FROM `deposits` WHERE `tradeid`=\''+offer.id+'\'');
                connection.query('DELETE FROM `withdraw` WHERE `tradeid`=\''+offer.id+'\'');
           
            });
});
 
setInterval(function() {
  checkDeposit();
  checkWithdraw();
}, 5000);
 
//Numeric and float
function is_float(mixed_var)
{
 
  return +mixed_var === mixed_var && (!isFinite(mixed_var) || !! (mixed_var % 1));
}
 
function isNumeric(n){
  return (typeof n == "number" && !isNaN(n));
}
 
//Setting up chat commands for the admin
client.on('friendMessage#'+admin+'', function(steamID, message)
{
 
    console.log("[SERVER] Admin to Bot: " + message);
    if((message.indexOf("ping") == 0) || (message.indexOf("/cmd") == 0))
    {
        checkDeposit();
        client.chatMessage(admin, 'Pong!');
    }
    if((message.indexOf("pong") == 0) || (message.indexOf("/cmd") == 0))
    {
        checkWithdraw();
        client.chatMessage(admin, 'Pong!');
    }
    if(message.indexOf("/code") == 0)
    {
        var code = SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(sharedsecret);
        client.chatMessage(admin, '[SERVER] Your login code: '+code+'');
    }  
 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understod your question right this is where the error occur.

```
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `withdraw` WHERE active=1  AND `botid`='"+botid+"' AND tradestatus='Queued' LIMIT 1", function(err, row, fields) {
if (!row.length) {                                                  
    return;
}
```

Im kind of new too the mysql area but i whould try to write the code something like this instead:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM `withdraw` WHERE active=1  AND `botid`= ? AND tradestatus='Queued' LIMIT 1",botid , function(err, rows, fields) {
if (!rows.length) {                                                  
    return;
}
```

What ive done is changed the place where you input the "botid" to a "?" instead, that takes the value from the botid right before your function, and row is now rows just for code clearance.

As you said, i cant access your DB but i hope that this might work. Let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that dosen't seem to make it work.

Comment: Still get the usual: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined